# My website not loading showing "page is not working"

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

my website not loading 5 hours now. please look this screen shot 
[error_sample](https://prnt.sc/jy4uch)

It showing last error in error log on cpanel like "WordPress database error Query execution was interrupted for query SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = '_transient_doing_cron' LIMIT 1 made by _get_cron_lock"

how to fix it? please help

Comment: when changing ISP it loads first time, then getting the same error. also tried to clear browser cache

Comment: Loads fine for me. Tried it several times.

Comment: but i cant, tries with different browser,device even cpanel not loading some time

Answer (score 0):

Its loading fine for me

The following might cause ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE,

1. A bad network connection
2. Certain running programs, such as Extensions, that may affect or corrupt your PC or the Google Chrome browser
3. Failure to clean the browser cache
4. Error caused by certain Temp Files

Comment: This problem not only for me, it effecting lot of visitors and also effecting the same websites under this hosting